# Video element event binding not working in Safari browser

Tags: wordpress, video, safari, mediaelement.js

I am using [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress) default core player [mediaelement.js](/questions/tagged/mediaelement.js) to play self-hosted videos.
By putting the `[video]` shortcode, I am generating the video rendering code in the front end.

For event binding I am using the Mediaelement's events as described [here](http://mediaelementjs.com/#plugins):

```
$('video').bind('loadeddata', function(e) { 
    alert('loaded');
});
$('video').bind('playing', function(e) { 
    alert('playing');
});
$('video').bind('pause', function(e) { 
    alert('pause');
});
$('video').bind('ended', function(e) { 
    alert('ended');
});
```

This is working perfectly in Internet Explorer and Firefox. But in case of [safari](/questions/tagged/safari), it's not working.

Please provide any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the weird behavior of Safari Browser as explained by [Johndyer](https://github.com/johndyer) in issue number [#536](https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/536) quoting below:

> This is a really frustrating part of [safari](/questions/tagged/safari) in that it only happens
>   when [quicktime](/questions/tagged/quicktime) isn't installed. In that case, Safari still acts like
>   it understands HTML5, but it fails in strange ways that I haven't been
>   able to detect. So just install QuickTime adn you'll be all set.

Its is working fine with Quicktime installation.